# protobuf-net - problem with deserializing on C++ side :(

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using ProtoBuf-Net in my .NET application to serialize the following : (in .proto format)

```
message ProtoScreenBuffer {
optional int32 MediaId = 1;
optional bytes Data = 2;
optional bool LastBuffer = 3;
optional int64 StartTime = 4;
optional int64 StopTime = 5;
optional int32 Flags = 6;
optional int32 BufferSubType = 7;
optional int32 BufferType = 8;
optional Guid Guid = 9;
repeated int32 EncryptedDataStart = 10;
repeated int32 EncryptedDataLength = 11;
}
```

My aim is to serialize this and inject it into an ASF file, as a single sample.

I call this to serialize :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize<ProtoScreenBuffer>(ms, ProtoScreenBuffer.CreateProtoScreenBuffer (buffer));
```

then I get a byte array from the ms object :

```
ms.ToArray();
```

and I put this byte array in the ASF.  The big problem is on my C++ app which reads the ASF sample just fine, I get a memory access violation when I try to deserialize it :(

this is my C++ code :

```
m_screenBuffer.ParseFromArray(serBuffer, dwInputDataLen);
```

(where m_screenBuffer is ProtoScreenBuffer, serBuffer is the raw byte array I got from the ASF file, and dwInputDataLen is the length of it.)

Are any of the things I'm doing here wrong , for what I'm trying to do (serialize in C# .NET and deserialize in C++?)

Thanks alot.

Roey

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried deserializing in Java, or with my C# port instead? That would give some indication as to whether it's the C++ or protobuf-net that's causing the problem.

Comment: How much effort is it to port my code to use your C# port?

Comment: Hi Jon, I cannot create the code using protogen.exe.
I get an exception : 
Error: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.

why is this?

Comment: just to confirm; that last line relates to @Jon's protogen, not mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... the only thing in there that I might expect to be messy is the `Guid` (I recently realised that my encoding of this appears to be fairly crazy-endian). So I *think* that should work fine, give or take some messy code to decipher the `Guid`.

To rule out an encoding error, what I would suggest is:

- serialize the data via C#, to a file (or just look at the bytes on-screen in the debugger)
- serialize the /same/ data via C++, to a file (or just look at the bytes on-screen in the debugger)

Then:

- compare the bytes
- check the length is what you expect (i.e. the number you are passing over)

That should indicate whether it is the encoding, vs something to do with passing the wrong memory address or similar.

Also - check you aren't using `GetBuffer()` (or at least, if you *do* use `GetBuffer()`, make sure you use the `.Length` from the `MemoryStream`, and not from the oversized `byte[]`).

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for replying, the GUID is basically : 

    message Guid { 
   optional fixed64 lo = 1; // the first 8 bytes of the guid 
   optional fixed64 hi = 2; // the second 8 bytes of the guid 
 } 

I will try to compare the two.. thanks

Comment: that came out a bit messy.
I meant the GUID is the format you gave me a few days ago, and I will try to compare the C# and C++ version :)

Thanks

Comment: Marc, I have compared what I serialize in the .NET application and what I try to deserialize in the C++ app, and they are 100% identical, and I also removed the GUI parameter.
It seems the access violation occurs when google protobuffs c++ is trying to decode the "data" field.
Would you prefer I start a thread somewhere else to discuss this?

Comment: I'm very glad that the output is identical. That shifts a burden ;-p I think the best place for C++ issues would be here: http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/topics , and you'll be looking for a reply from Kenton Varda.

Comment: Can I be 100% sure that the protobuf-net serializes my data correctly?
should the "bytes" field have a length at all? or will it serialize any length I give it?

Comment: I don't see a `bytes` field - which `bytes` field do you mean?

Comment: Or is `bytes` the parameter to `ParseFromArray`?